# does a weak named .NET assembly contains a manifest with a hash

Tags: .net, security, hash

One feature of the .NET assembly with a strong name is the resistance to tampering. Once the hash of the assembly content is calculated, it is encrypted with a private key, and then saved as a part of assembly's manifest.
I am wondering - what if the assembly does not have a strong name, what happens with a hash? Is it saved to the manifest unencrypted?

Comment: The unencrypted SHA-1 hash isn't stored anywhere, it is always calculated when needed.

Comment: Thank you Hans. That means if the assembly does not have a strong name, it's manifest does not contain SHA-1 hash, right?

Comment: @hans-passat btw, in which situation there might be a need to calculate content's hash for the assembly with no strong name?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the hash evidence of a PE format file and the strong name of a .Net assembly. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2005/02/28/382027.aspx for a good explanation.